# Connected GitHub and JIRA - changes are not syncing across platforms

Tags: github, integration, jira, synchronization

I have connected both platforms through DVCS accounts, and then pulled in my existing issues on GitHub into a JIRA Project.

Despite all of this, when I now update anything (commenting on an issue or creating a new issue) in JIRA or GitHub, I am unable to see this change reflected in the other platform.

How can I push the project to update on the JIRA side and on the other side (and most importantly) - make sure that GitHub updates if I add new issues in JIRA